# How to get total size of photo in Pillow?

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, python-imaging-library

I want to get total size of photo in MB but I get only ExifImageWidth and ExifImageHeight.
How can I do this?

**Code:**

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL.ExifTags import TAGS

image = Image.open('images\DJI_0001.jpg')

exifdata = image.getexif()

for tag_id in exifdata:
    tag = TAGS.get(tag_id, tag_id)
    data = exifdata.get(tag_id)
    if isinstance(data, bytes):
        try:
            data = data.decode()
        except:
            continue
    print(f"{tag}: {data}")
```

Comment: Try `file_size = os.stat('d:/file.jpg')` followed by `print("Size of file :", file_size.st_size, "bytes")`

Comment: By the way, you probably want `MB` (megabytes) rather than `mb` (millibits)  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Megabyte

Comment: @MarkSetchell Yes, you have right. I will corret this.

Comment: sys.getsizeof(object[, default]):   that would translate into sys.getsizeof(YOURIMAGE), than translate from bytes to MB